# How to get the number of chips left outside fixed size chipGroup

Tags: android, material-design, android-design-library, material-components-android, android-chips

I use ChipGroup in fragment to put entries I picked up from the list

```
 <com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup
                android:id="@+id/cgGroup"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/bounds_xxl"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/bounds_l"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/bounds_l"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/bounds_l"
                android:background="@drawable/item_grey_box"
                android:drawableEnd="@drawable/ic_pick_icon"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:paddingEnd="@dimen/bounds_m"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tvLabelGroup"
                bind:bindFilterViewModel="@{viewModelFilter}"
                bind:onClick="@{fragmentFilter}"
                tools:ignore="RtlSymmetry" />
```

Since my ChipGroup height is going to be fixed size, if I add more Chip views to ChipGroup than it can fit, then only first few will be shown and the rest will remain hidden. So I want to get number of those hidden chips in order to  show some "+5 more" text label under the ChipGroup. I tried:

```
 var invisibleElements = 0
            chipGroup.forEach { chip ->
                if (!(chip as Chip).isVisible) {
                  invisibleElements++
                }
            }
```

but then I realized I never actually set that chips to invisible. In fact they are set to View.VISIBLE by default but it is the ChipGroup that could not show them all.
I don't want to set my ChipGroup scrollable or something like that, i just want some kind of `chipGroup.hiddenChildCount` method

Comment: You can wrap the ChipGroup in a HorizontalScrollView just to avoid this scenario

Comment: Yes, I know that but that's not desired scenario. I would like ChipGroup to take as many Chips it can show, and rest to be counted and their count presented in label like "+ 5 more".